# How To Enable a Hyper-link To Open a Modal Dialog whilst also allowing Open in New Tab on the same link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications

I am developing a webpage. On the webpage is a hyper-link, called "View Page". Once clicked, the aim is that this will display the linked-to-page in a modal dialog.

Here is the code that I use to achieve this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

        <script>
           function OpenModal() {
                $("#divModal").dialog({
                    autoOpen: false, modal: true, title: 'Modal', width: 'auto', height: 'auto'
                    , buttons: { "Cancel": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } },
                }).dialog('open');
                return false;
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="#" onclick="javascript:OpenModal();">View Page</a>
        <div style="display:none;" id="divModal">
            <iframe id="myIframe" src="SomeValidURL" width="1100" height="800" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way that functionality similar to that below can be implemented to allow the user to right click on the *View Page* link, select “Open in New Tab” or *Open in New Window* and have *SomeValidUrl* open in the new tab or new window?  If the user Left Clicks *SomeValidUrl* the page should open in the modal dialog.

Comment: I would remove the `onclick` and then use a normal click event, then detect what kind of click event it was (left, right or middle) and react accordingly. (Hint: you only want to open the modal on left click). Also would need to add the url to the href.

Comment: The reason why all you get is the main page opened in the tab, is because of your `href="#"`.

Answer (score 2):

There is really no problem with `return false`. Actually you should! If you don't `return false` or `preventDefault` your modal will open and then the link will trigger, forwarding you to the other page.

If you want this to work just if the user right clicks his way through the link to open it in a new window/tab, it is sufficient for you to put `SomeValidURL` (that you have in the `src` attribute of your `iframe`) for the `href` attribute of the `a` element.

Also, as a general tip, avoid binding events inline; rather use [`jQuery.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/): it is more flexible, it sticks to the best practice of separation of concerns, and it really helps with clutter.

Comment: Ahah thank you, I was quite enjoying the 999 reputation: funny coincidence.

Comment: Click on any post score! You'll be amazed.

Comment: Ah! Indeed no fancy notification introduced me to the privileges of the 1-thousand-s. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to the links then use this.

```
  $(".link").mousedown(function(event) {
        switch (event.which) {
            case 1:
                //modal code
                break;
            case 3:
                window.open("http://www.google.com", '_blank');
                break;
            default :
                window.open("http://www.google.com", '_blank');
                break;
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/Er7NN/

Answer (score 0):

Then allow the normal use of the link, with the `href` attribute:

```
<a href="SomeValidURL" onclick="javascript:OpenModal();">View Page</a>
```

Despite the `return false`, this should still work, since your `click` handler is not involved when right-clicking and selecting "open in new tab" from the resulting browser-rendered context menu.